# "System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified" in MvvmCross TableView binding

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, mvxbind

Hopefully someone can help me with the following, because I am completely stuck.

I receive the exception below in my MvvmCross Xamarin.iOS application when I bind on my TableView. This only happens when I change the datasource (each time I change the date, the TableView needs to get updated).

```
Incident Identifier: 7E7C2B15-7CC4-4AE7-9891-C4FD82358009
CrashReporter Key:   46CC21C0-DDE1-4313-9658-EC79D767939B
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,2
Process:         UurwerkiOS [4326]
Path:            /var/containers/Bundle/Application/75969477-A516-44C3-A5A3-5B24DDDC89C8/UurwerkiOS.app/UurwerkiOS
Identifier:      com.route2it.uurwerk
Version:         1.0 (1.0.96)
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2016-07-04T13:16:38Z
Launch Time:     2016-07-04T13:16:31Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 9.3.2 (13F69)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x1816ac11c
Crashed Thread:  5

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.AggregateException', reason: 'System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException (ExceptionResource resource) <0x10044bec0 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare () <0x1003bf900 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () <0x1003bf830 + 0x0009f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxTaskBasedBindingContext.<OnDataContextChange>b__20_0 () <0x1007c1990 + 0x0023f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () <0x10043f1f0 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <0x10043ea20 + 0x00043> in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException (ExceptionResource resource) <0x10044bec0 + 0x00024> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNextRare () <0x1003bf900 + 0x0002f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1+Enumerator[T].MoveNext () <0x1003bf830 + 0x0009f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxTaskBasedBindingContext.<OnDataContextChange>b__20_0 () <0x1007c1990 + 0x0023f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () <0x10043f1f0 + 0x0005f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () <0x10043ea20 + 0x00043> in <filename unknown>:0
```

At first I thought it was related to one of my Async methods (which maybe not complete in time while the next one was already running). So I removed all my async code, but the exception still occurs. I also made sure I don't change the enumerable collection myself. I fetch the data (which is simply a in memory array) and return it as a new list to the property to which the TableView is bound. Below are the code snippets that make up the binding (it's a lot of information but I wanted to be as complete as possible):

**CalendarViewController:**

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        if (NavigationController != null)
                NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;

        InitCalendar();
        InitNavigationItem();
        InitTableView();

        ApplyConstraints();

        var shiftForDateTableViewSource = new MvxSimpleTableViewSource(_tableView, CalendarTableViewCell.Key, CalendarTableViewCell.Key);
        shiftForDateTableViewSource.DeselectAutomatically = true;
        _tableView.RowHeight = 45;
        _tableView.Source = shiftForDateTableViewSource;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CalendarView, CalendarViewModel>();
        set.Bind(shiftForDateTableViewSource).To(vm => vm.ShiftsForSelectedDate);
        set.Bind(shiftForDateTableViewSource).For(vm => vm.SelectionChangedCommand).To(vm => vm.ShiftSelectedCommand);
        set.Apply();

        _tableView.ReloadData();
}

private void InitTableView()
{
        _tableView = new UITableView();
        _tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(UITableViewCell), CalendarTableViewCell.Key);

        Add(_tableView);
}
```

**CalendarTableViewCell:**

```
public partial class CalendarTableViewCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("CalendarTableViewCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    static CalendarTableViewCell()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName("CalendarTableViewCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    protected CalendarTableViewCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CalendarTableViewCell, Shift>();
        set.Bind(StartTimeLabel).To(vm => vm.StartDate).WithConversion("StringFormat", "HH:mm");
        set.Bind(EndTimeLabel).To(vm => vm.EndDate).WithConversion("StringFormat", "HH:mm");
        set.Bind(ColorBarView).For("BackgroundColor").To(vm => vm.Color).WithConversion("RGB");
        set.Bind(TitleLabel).To(vm => vm).WithConversion("ConcatenatedEventTitle");
        set.Bind(LocationLabel).To(vm => vm.Location);
        set.Apply();

    }
}
```

**CalendarViewModel:**

```
public class CalendarViewModel
        : MvxViewModel
{
        private readonly IShiftService _shiftService;

        public CalendarViewModel(IShiftService shiftService)
        {
                if (shiftService == null)
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(shiftService));

                _shiftService = shiftService;
        }

        public override void Start()
        {
                base.Start();

                Shifts = _shiftService.GetShiftsForEmployeeAsync(1);
        }

        private IEnumerable<Shift> _shifts;
        public IEnumerable<Shift> Shifts
        {
                get { return _shifts; }
                set
                {
                        SetProperty(ref _shifts,
                                                value,
                                                nameof(Shifts));
                }
        }

        private IEnumerable<Shift> _shiftsForSelectedDate;
        public IEnumerable<Shift> ShiftsForSelectedDate
        {
                get { return _shiftsForSelectedDate; }
                private set
                {
                        if (_shiftsForSelectedDate == value)
                                return;

                        SetProperty(ref _shiftsForSelectedDate,
                                                value,
                                                nameof(ShiftsForSelectedDate));
                }
        }

        private DateTime? _selectedDate;
        public DateTime? SelectedDate
        {
                get { return _selectedDate; }
                set
                {
                        if (_selectedDate == value)
                                return;

                        SetProperty(ref _selectedDate,
                                                value,
                                                nameof(SelectedDate));

                        if (_selectedDate.HasValue)
                                FetchShiftsForSelectedDate();
                }
        }

        private void FetchShiftsForSelectedDate()
        {
                ShiftsForSelectedDate = _shiftService.GetShiftsForSelectedDateAsync(_selectedDate.Value);
        }
}
```

**MockShiftService (implements the IShiftService interface):**

```
public class MockShiftService
        : IShiftService
{
        private IList<Shift> _shifts;

        public MockShiftService()
        {
                Initialize();
        }

        public IEnumerable<Shift> GetShiftsForEmployeeAsync(int employeeId)
        {
                return _shifts;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Shift> GetShiftsForSelectedDateAsync(DateTime selectedDate)
        {
                var endDate = selectedDate.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59));

                return _shifts
                                                        .Where(s => s.StartDate <= endDate && s.EndDate >= selectedDate)
                                                        .ToList();
        }

        public Shift GetShiftByIdAsync(int shiftId)
        {
                return _shifts.First((shift) => shift.Id == shiftId);
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
                var shifts = new List<Shift>();

                // The in memory array gets populated here which 
                // is straight forward creating instances of the
                // 'Shift' class and assigning it's properties before
                // adding it to the 'shifts' collection. I left
                // this code out to keep it as short as possible.
        }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I have referenced my project directly to the debug assemblies of MvvmCross and figured out that the exception is thrown on line 127 of the `MvxTaskBasedBindingContext` class and always happens on the second iteration. From this I conclude that the collection is changed during the first iteration. Unfortunately I cannot figure out why or how.

I noticed that the `MvxTaskBasedBindingContext` replaces the `MvxBindingContext` (changed by softlion on 11-5-2016). When I force my application to use the `MvxBindingContext` class all works well (although a bit laggy). This makes me believe the problem is in the `MvxTaskBasedBindingContext` but I really can't figure out why, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE 2:**

After some more debugging and fiddling around I found out that the exception is related to the bindings set by my `CalendarTableViewCell` class (which should provide the layout for each item in the tableview defined in my `CalendarViewController`. When I comment out the bindings in the `CalendarTableViewCell` class the exception does not occur (see my code above). I still don't know what could be wrong though.

Comment: What version of MvvmCross? I think something like this has already been addressed.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue in versions 4.2.0, 4.2.1 and 4.2.2.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with iOS, but one thing I have noticed is they tend to use `DelayBind`. So perhaps wrapping your MvxTableViewCell binding in a `this.DelayBind(() => { /* your code for binding in LayoutSubviews here */});` may help? Pure guessing, I have no idea how iOS works lols.

Comment: @PlaceHold3r, nice observation. I added the DelayBind and I no longer get the error. Perfect! Please add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as answer and award you the bounty.

Comment: @MauritsvanBeusekom, glad to hear this solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `DelayBind` in your `CalendarTableViewCell` to delay binding until your [`DataContext`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/Binding/iOS/Views/MvxTableViewCell.cs#L103) gets set on your [`BindingContext`](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/2660e6ff1368e63ccd6f12eb408cf7fe0957db8c/MvvmCross/Core/Binding/BindingContext/MvxBindingContext.cs#L219)

```
public partial class CalendarTableViewCell : MvxTableViewCell
{
    ...

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        this.DelayBind(() =>
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<CalendarTableViewCell, Shift>();
            set.Bind(StartTimeLabel).To(vm => vm.StartDate).WithConversion("StringFormat", "HH:mm");
            set.Bind(EndTimeLabel).To(vm => vm.EndDate).WithConversion("StringFormat", "HH:mm");
            set.Bind(ColorBarView).For("BackgroundColor").To(vm => vm.Color).WithConversion("RGB");
            set.Bind(TitleLabel).To(vm => vm).WithConversion("ConcatenatedEventTitle");
            set.Bind(LocationLabel).To(vm => vm.Location);
            set.Apply();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem will not be fixed with delay binding.
The problem is that the Lists are enumerated in a Task, which can be modified while the enumeration is going on.

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (var binding in this._viewBindings)
    {
         foreach (var bind in binding.Value)
         {
             bind.Binding.DataContext = this._dataContext;
         }
    }

    foreach (var binding in this._directBindings)
    {
         binding.Binding.DataContext = this._dataContext;
    }
```

});

Before enumerating need to create copy of collection ToList() or ToArray().

This bug has beed already reported.
[Link](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1398)

Comment: I agree that the problem is not fixed with delay binding. However it seems to be a good workaround for the problem (until someone solves the actual problem, which might be me).